# default scale of bigdecimal in groovy

Tags: groovy, bigdecimal

What is the default scale of BigDecimal in groovy? And Rounding?

So when trying to do calculations:

```
def x = 10.0/30.0 //0.3333333333
def y = 20.0/30.0 //0.6666666667
```

Base on this, I can assume that it uses scale 10 and rounding half up.
Having trouble finding an official documentation saying that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in the official documentation: [The case of the division operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#integer_division)

> 5.5.1. The case of the division operator
>
> The division operators / (and /= for division and assignment) produce
>   a double result if either operand is a float or double, and a
>   BigDecimal result otherwise (when both operands are any combination of
>   an integral type short, char, byte, int, long, BigInteger or
>   BigDecimal).
>
> BigDecimal division is performed with the divide() method if the
>   division is exact (i.e. yielding a result that can be represented
>   within the bounds of the same precision and scale), or using a
>   MathContext with a precision of the maximum of the two operands'
>   precision ***plus an extra precision of 10, and a scale of the maximum of
>   10 and the maximum of the operands' scale***.

And check it in [`BigDecimalMath.java`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/BigDecimalMath.java):

```
public Number divideImpl(Number left, Number right) {
    BigDecimal bigLeft = toBigDecimal(left);
    BigDecimal bigRight = toBigDecimal(right);
    try {
        return bigLeft.divide(bigRight);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        // set a DEFAULT precision if otherwise non-terminating
        int precision = Math.max(bigLeft.precision(), bigRight.precision()) + DIVISION_EXTRA_PRECISION;
        BigDecimal result = bigLeft.divide(bigRight, new MathContext(precision));
        int scale = Math.max(Math.max(bigLeft.scale(), bigRight.scale()), DIVISION_MIN_SCALE);
        if (result.scale() > scale) result = result.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit late to ask, but, how did you know that BigDecimalMath.java is being used?