# How does groovy runtime typehandling works?

Tags: groovy, runtime

I recently found out that groovy uses NumberMath implementations to do math calculations.

So:

```
BigDecimal x = 1.0/30.0
```

Uses [BigDecimalMath.java](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/BigDecimalMath.html) to set the precision and scale. I just learned about this on [one of the posts here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951371/default-scale-of-bigdecimal-in-groovy). But I'm still puzzled how it works.

So, how does this work in general? And are there documentations out there about runtime typehandling or the likes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @tim_yates I mean, how are they factored in? Are they added on runtime?

Comment: Sorry...are what added at Runtime?

Comment: @tim_yates Sorry, I was under the assumption that the metaclass was being altered in Runtime. How does the NumberMath logic comes in?

Answer (score 2):

The code `BigDecimal x = 1.0/30.0` is compiled by the Groovy compiler and can there of course easily emit code, that will call into the runtime. If we leave out the callsite caching and all the call logic, what happens is that NumberMath#getMath is called. This method decides using the operand types, what math implementation will be used. The information about the operation comes then later in as method call name from the call site. Since 1.0 and 30.0 are both BigDecimal in Groovy (suffix D or d to make it a double) BigDecimalMath#divideImpl will be used in the end. This method then calls BigDecimal#divide. Since the given expression would require a BigDecimal of endless length a scale and precision is set, which is the maximum of the operands and 10 and default rounding mode. As for who does select the types... this is done in the call site implementation classes based on the actual objects, using getClass(), sometimes static information is used, if runtime and static type are supposed the some (hint: final classes).

Comment: Thanks for answering, this was very helpful. Can you point me to some documentation about this so I could delve in more?